# Pass build variables to powershell inline script in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have set a build variable which I would like to consume in my inline powershell script.

I tried $($myvariable) but this comes out blank.

Answer (score 15):

> Pass build variables to powerhshell inline script in Azure DevOps

To get the build variables with inline power shell script, you can try to use following syntax `$env:variable`:

```
$env:myvariable
```

[image]

The build variable:

[image]

The build result:

[image]

Note:At this moment, the value of nested variables (like `$(myvariable$(Build.SourceBranchName))`) on build variables table are not yet supported in the build pipelines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops#arguments

Comment: How would you get the secret variables passed into the inline script like this? I have used ConvertTo-SecureString "$($password)" -AsPlainText -Force, but that was the $ password was passed into an external script. It didn't work for inline scripts.

Answer (score 5):

here's what's working for me:

```
$(variableName)
```

for example built-in variable called Build.BuildNumber can be accessed like so:

```
$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

full example with format function:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@3
  displayName: UpdatePrereq
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
        ${{ format('. $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\scripts\_helpers.ps1
        Update-DeploymentPrereq -resourceGroup {1} -location {3}
        Update-Prereq -pathSuffix {0} -pathBase $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) -resourceGroup {1} -buildId $(Build.BuildNumber) -paramFile {2}
        Update-DeploymentConcurrency -resourceGroup {1} -buildId $(Build.BuildNumber)',
            parameters.buildDir, parameters.resourceGroupName, parameters.paramFile, parameters.location ) }}
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use nested variables you can use something like this:

```
$name = "CONNECTIONSTRING_$(Agent.MachineName)"
$val = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($name)
```

And then you get the value of the variable ConnectionString.MACHINENAME

Answer (score 0):

Use $env:variableName

If your variable names contain dots, replace the dots with underscore:

```
  Write-Host "variable.name= $env:variable_name"
```